# json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []main.KVU

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm new to golang and I'd like to get a json object into my code:

```
func getUserRandking() []KVU {    
    url := "http://127.0.0.1:8080/users"

    spaceClient := http.Client{         Timeout: time.Second * 10, 
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "spacecount-tutorial")

    res, getErr := spaceClient.Do(req)
    if getErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(getErr)
    }

    body, readErr := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if readErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(readErr)
    }

    var users1 []KVU
    jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(body, &users1)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(jsonErr)
    }

    fmt.Println(users1)

    return users1

}
```

but I get this runtime error

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []main.KVU exit
>   status 1

The json that I'm trying to import is like this:

```
{
  "name": "userslist",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "cat",
      "value": 1,
      "url": "http://example.com/1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "dog",
      "value": 2,
      "url": "http://example.com/2.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried different type definitions like `Users` below:

```
type KVU struct {
    Key   string `json:"name"`
    Value int    `json:"value"`
    Url   string `json:"url"`
}

type Users struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Children []KVU  `json:"children"`
}
```

But that also leads to:

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []main.Users

How can I fix this?

Comment: The structure of the Go data structure must match the JSON. Your JSON is an object so marshal into a struct and not into a slice (which would be appropriate for a JSON array).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is because you have to create `Users` struct rather than `KUV` for unmarshalling the JSON. Since []KVU is a slice which will unmarshal the array of `children` which is an array of Objects. Also you need to parse the Json returned from the server to remove escape characters like `/`. Use `strconv.Unquote` to manage with escaped JSON.

```
func Unquote(s string) (string, error)
```

> Unquote interprets s as a single-quoted, double-quoted, or backquoted
>   Go string literal, returning the string value that s quotes. (If s is
>   single-quoted, it would be a Go character literal; Unquote returns the
>   corresponding one-character string.)

Check below working Code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type KVU struct {
    Key   string `json:"name"`
    Value int    `json:"value"`
    Url   string `json:"url"`
}

type Users struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Children []KVU  `json:"children"`
}

func main() {
    result := getUserRandking()
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func getUserRandking() []KVU{
    input := `"{\"name\":\"userslist\",\"children\":[{\"name\":\"kachalmooferfer\",\"value\":444,\"url\":\"http://pbs.twimg.com/p‌​rofile_images/989898400609992704/UE8HiRVx_normal.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"patrick_jane7‌​7\",\"value\":407,\"url\":\"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/94467727094959308‌​9/zv62U1ch_normal.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"Pensylvani\",\"value\":213,\"url\":\"http://‌​pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1018010357892198400/Rw06UWvY_normal.jpg\"}]}"`
    var val []byte = []byte(input)
    jsonInput, err := strconv.Unquote(string(val))
    if err !=nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    var resp Users
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonInput), &resp)
    // Return below struct slice for Children from the function 
    return resp.Children
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GEoTN2G9RnN) Example

Comment: Well this removes the original error but now I get: `json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type main.Users
exit status 1
`

Comment: Let me check because I have tested in on Go playground it is working fine.

Comment: Yea, but I need to get the json inside `getUserRandking` function. Appreciate if you can revamp the code.

Comment: Well, it there: The code sample starts with `func getUserRandking() {...` How can you see it?

Comment: @Babr, simply `return resp.Children` then.

Comment: @Babr Can you print the output of `fmt.Println(string(body))`

Comment: @Himanshu, The result is like `"{\"name\":\"userslist\",\"children\":[{\"name\":\"cat\",\"value\":107,\"url\":\"http://example.com/1.jpg\"},...`

Comment: @Babr Please check updated code for returning `Children` Slice from `getUserRandking()` function

Comment: Well by using `return users1.Children` I still get `json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type main.Users`

Comment: @Babr Well Check Edited code according to your provided function code and see the result also the return type should match the returned result of the function

Comment: Still the same issue: `func getUserRandking() []KVU {` with `return users1.Children` yeilds: `cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type main.Users`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176571/discussion-between-himanshu-and-babr).